# Vaadin, form.addListener protected access, can't use it as shown in crm tutorial, "addListener" no longer works

Tags: vaadin, event-listener

this was an issue I faced while following the CRM tutorial on Vaadin, and managed to solve it, and thought I might put it here, since I couldn't find elsewhere.

In the tutorial, which is made with Vaadin 21-22, while right now we are at V24. The issue is, in the tutorial he adds an event listener to the contact form, to save a contact, among other things. But in one of the following versions, this was turned into a protected version, and a new method addSaveListener was implemented, which ofcourse replaces it.

Simply:
Tutorial uses addListener
This is now a protected method that can't be used as shown in the video
The solution is to use the addSaveListener, with the only argument being: this::saveContact

Proof, or how I found out, is that in the github repo, with the project files, it is shown this way.

https://github.com/vaadin/flow-crm-tutorial/blob/8829b2191278491f8ffa4dbb5a60127895cd5660/src/main/java/com/example/application/views/list/ListView.java

Good luck everyone

I tried making sure my code didn't have errors, that may have caused it in the first place.
Tried searching elsewhere, but it wasn't mentioned elsewhere, and the code wasn't really visible what is causing it.

Comment: You will have to split this into two parts. SO is a QnA-Page and not a forum. Change your question into "addListener" no longer works. And then create an answer, that "addSaveListener" replaced the function since V23.

Answer (score 0):

"addSaveListener" replaced the function since V23.